# How can I keep my tribe happy with me being king?

Tags: king-of-dragon-pass

I'm trying a long game in *King of Dragon Pass*, PC version. My problem is this: how by Elmal's balls and Orlanth's fart can I keep my tribe-mates happy?

I am really confused as to what influences tribe-mood. My clan is prosperous, I almost have more cows than people (seriously, I have like 1000 people and at the moment, around 1900+ cows), I usually make massive damages on any fool attempting to raid my tula, I have enough treasures to start a museum. To boot, my clan's mood is pretty damn happy, if not downright jubilant. I always keep the tribal judge in "by the strength of the case" (or whatever it is that says that the king judges the case by legal merit rather than who is most generous or how they are disposed towards me).

But how can I fulfill my destiny if my tribe-mates constantly want to depose our king? They say something vague about "dishonored our ancestry" or whatever. The manual is unhelpful. The only way I know to increase tribe mood is by doing a heroquest.

One of my advisors say something about "sending emissaries" to tribe-mates, but most of these clans are happy with me. Even if that is so, I am confused as to what I should do. Sending gifts to them occasionally seems pointless.

I am sincerely at loss as to what to do.

Comment: http://kingofdragonpass.blogspot.com/2013/12/friends-and-relations.html has a little about tribal mood.

Answer (score 2):

Gifts never hurt, though they IIRC they really only affect underlying clan attitudes, and not what other clans think about membership in this tribe thing. Be careful in judging between tribe-mates.

Also, if you barely got a tribe put together, people start with misgivings, and it is easier to fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Some clans nurse grievances.  Something that may help target the gift-giving David is correct to advise, is trying to find out which tribe member is spreading the poison with Lhankhor Mhy divination on each of the other clans in the tribe. This might show up someone who has a basically positive attitude but can't forget a past slight - the Elmali neighbour seems particularly likely to hold a grievance over what they regard as impious behaviour.  Enough generosity will heal this old wound.

Comment: http://kingofdragonpass.blogspot.com/2014/03/slights-make-war-but-favors-make-peace.html has some details on this.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question was posted, but in case anyone else comes across this question, I had the same problem. The Tribe hated my clan's king, despite all being blue-purple and seemingly happy with my clan and my clan itself had high morale. If I were to guess, I'm guessing the problem is some of the clans in your tribe don't like each other and as result you as the king get the blame for their problems.

Easiest way to fix this is to perform the Hero Quest of "Chalana Arroy heals the scars". One of the rewards is to heal tribal rifts. It took my tribe outlook from "disappointed" to "optimistic" after successful completion.